# How to render component onClick in React after passing props?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How do you update the LatestTweetsComponent with the data returned from a fetch call that happens in handleRequest? `tweets` is updating correctly onClick however the LatestTweetsComponent does not render or update. I may be approaching this incorrectly.

```
const LatestTweets = () => {
  const [tweets, setTweets] = useState(null)

  const handleRequest = async () => {
    // this hits an api to get tweets and sets the tweets
    // is this where the LatestTweetsComponent render is called?
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleRequest()}>View Latest Tweets</button>
      <LatestTweetsComponent tweets={tweets} />
    </div>
  )
}

const LatestTweetsComponent = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.map((tweet, index) => {
        return <p key={index}>{tweet}</p>
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default LatestTweets
```

Comment: `props.map` in `LatestTweetsComponent` should be `props.tweets?.map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is because you are trying to map over "props", while you should be mapping over "props.tweets"
try this :

```js
const LatestTweetsComponent = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.tweets.map((tweet, index) => {
        return <p key={index}>{tweet}</p>
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use that handleFetch in useEffect. So, whenever your state gets change useeffect will rerender that change.

And use tweets as  argument in useEffect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).